# Objective C - TextField size

Tags: string, dynamic, textfield

i've a string that i have to place in a UITextField. But my TextField have not to be scrollable, but have to size itself based on the string length. How can i do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGSize stringSize=[[stringName sizeWithFont:UIFont constrainedToSize:fontSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWrap]];
```

From `stringSize.heigth` you can size the TextField.